# Inverse Function Theorem. On the classical method of proof.

Tags: analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, math-history

The proof most commonly of the [Inverse Function Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) seen in textbooks of relies on the [Banach fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).

> **QUESTION.** 
>   It is possible to say, using historical references, which mathematician was the idea of using Banach's Contration Principle to prove the inverse function theorem ? If not, in which reference of the  century XIX or century XX first appeared this proof?

I did a search on the Mathematics history books specialized in the subject. For example:

- Krantz, Steven G.; Parks, Harold R. [The implicit function theorem. History, theory, and applications. Birkhäuser Boston, Inc., Boston, MA, 2002.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/146145980X)
- Dontchev, Asen L.; Rockafellar, R. Tyrrell [Implicit functions and solution mappings. A view from variational analysis. Springer Monographs in Mathematics. Springer, Dordrecht, 2009](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387878203)

But I did not get (at least my noticing) any track.

Comment: Have you read this? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/94323/who-was-the-first-to-formulate-the-inverse-function-theorem

Comment: @Siminore No. I had not seen this issue in MathOverflow. The answer ultimately lead me to references I've consulted. Thanks anyway. +1.

Comment: Probably Stefan Banach himself in the 1920. Earlier proofs relied on the solution theory of differential equations for $y'=-F_y^{-1}F_x$.